# How to set permission to ALWAYS be full on for administrator?

Tags: users

I'm looking for a module that will give the administrator permission on ABSOLUTELY everything.

Not only to retroactively give all permissions after having installed modules in the past. But also for every new module installed.

By default giving the Administrator permission to do EVERYTHING.

I have tried:

https://www.drupal.org/project/fpa

But still a lot of configuration and clicking..

Isn't there a way to click on a sigle box and set everything to ON in one shot for administrator?

I'm the only one touching the website, no collaborators, EVER ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set Administrator role `/admin/config/people/accounts`?
[image]

Comment: It should be noted that there are some modules that don't follow best standards and will still block administrators if they don't have the correct permissions. (I've only found a few, poorly supported modules that were like this.)

Comment: That doesn't work, I keep having to reset permissions all the time, even on content types I create...